# how to apply focus on text area of react-mentions

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to change the border color on focus in this default object only , but it's not working. This is the  react-mentions package link- [React-Mentions](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions). Is there something I'm missing and did wrong?

this is the default style I used

```
export default {
  control: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },

  '&multiLine': {
    control: {
      fontFamily: 'monospace',
      minHeight: 63,
    },
    input: {
      padding: 9,
      border: '1px solid silver',
 '&focused': {
         border: '1px solid black',
      },
    },
  },

  suggestions: {
    list: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    item: {
      padding: '5px 15px',
      borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
      '&focused': {
        backgroundColor: '#cee4e5',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This is the Mention Code, apart from the styling issue it's working fine

```
const MentionInput = ({ options }) => {
  let [data, setData] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setData(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MentionsInput
        value={data}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="h-full"
        style={defaultStyle}
      >
        <Mention
          trigger="@"
          markup="@__display__ "
          data={options}
          appendSpaceOnAdd={true}
          displayTransform={(id, display) => {
            return `@${display}`;
          }}
          //   style={defaultMentionStyle}
        />
      </MentionsInput>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Styling MentionInput (including texarea)

**Answer**: use the `input` tag to style the `<textarea>` in `MentionInput` in general,

Here an **example** of an ugly styled `MentionInput` that might help:

[image]

I packed style in a js file `mentionInputStyle.js`

```
export default {

 control: {
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
 },

 input: {
  backgroundColor: "yellow",
  borderRadius: "20px"
 },


 '&multiLine': {
  control: {
   minHeight: 63,
  },
  highlighter: {
   padding: 9,
   border: '1px solid transparent',
  },
  input: {
   padding: 9,
   border: '1px solid silver',
  },
 },
 '&singleLine': {
  display: 'inline-block',
  width: 180,
  highlighter: {
   padding: 1,
   border: '1px inset transparent',
  },
  input: {
   padding: 1,
   border: '2px inset',
  },
 },
 suggestions: {
  list: {
   borderRadius: '10px',
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
   fontSize: 16,
  },
  item: {
   padding: "5px",
   margin: "3px",
   borderRadius: "8px",
   '&focused': {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(241,53,109,0.15)',
   },
  },
 },
}

}
```

In the file with my `MentionInput`:

```
import mentionsInputStyle from "./mentionInputStyle";

...


 const [value, setValue] = useState("");

 const users = [
  {
   id: "karl",
   display: "Karl Schmarl",
  },
  {
   id: "robin",
   display: "Robin Bobin",
  }
 ];


...
return (
   <MentionsInput
    style={mentionsInputStyle}
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}>


    <Mention
     data={users}
    />
   </MentionsInput>
)

...
```

P.S: example mostly comes from here: https://blog.logrocket.com/build-react-comment-form-mention-functionality/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this on my end!

I think they encapsulated the textarea with 2 divs, since it is inside a parant div you need to target the textarea:focus-visible css to get the styles for its focus

Comment: Hi @bon-andre-opina, could you provide an example code of the fix? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that you use [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to add styles to the components, I found this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mentions-bugfixing-77f2d?file=/src/App.tsx) will be very helpful to let you understand how can it be used with react mentions as well.
I think it's much easier